# How to share the authenticated user across all laravel views

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5.8

I have a very weird problem in **Laravel 5.8**. I wanna share the user variable with all views.

I added this to my `boot` method in `AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
Event::listen(Authenticated::class, function ($e) {
    view()->share('user', $e->user);
});
```

In the view, I have this:

```
@auth('web')
  {{$user->name}}
@endauth
```

The `User` model has

```
protected $guard = 'web';
```

It works most of the times, but sometimes I get this error:

```
Uncaught ErrorException: Undefined variable: user in /home/forge/www.mywebsite.com/storage/framework/views/4b273b493839e5fb54c3f6a2d11d9446bee5de33.php:11
```

How is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using view composers for shared variables around views

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard; 
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot(Guard $auth)
    {

        // Using Closure based composers...
        View::composer('*', function ($view) use ($auth) {
            $view->with('currentAuthenticatedUser', $auth->user());
        });
    }
}
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#view-composers)

Comment: This seems to be the cleanest answer. Calling `view()->share()` directly from the `boot` method of `AppServiceProvider` doesn't work because `Auth::user()` returns null no matter what.

Comment: What is the difference in behaviour with the previous answer?

Comment: "It appears that if you call $auth->user() in the boot() method (inside a service provider) and dd() it, it will return null.

BUT, if you're using a closure, you have to say 'use ($auth)' before the closure if the variable you want to use is not in scope."
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-do-i-get-the-current-authenticated-user-laravel-5

Comment: Your previous example was using the `Auth` facade which should work too, without injecting the Guard. The key is calling `auth()->user()` or `Auth::user()` inside the callback of a view composer. The callback gets executed at a later stage, when the view is being rendered and the user is thus available.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the authenticated user through the auth helper in your views.

`$user = auth()->user();`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/helpers#method-auth

UPDATE: In order to not repeat this in every view, you could fetch the user from the auth facade/helper in your layout files, that way the variable will be available in all views that extend that layout

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So it seems that the only solution is to use the `auth()` helper or the `Auth` facade and I can't share the `user` variable in the views. Is it correct?

Comment: Thats correct, however you can use the `$user`  variable directly without using the facade if you pass it to the view through the controller method.

Comment: Yeah, but that would mean duplicating `'user' => auth()->user()` in each controller. I thought there was a way to centralize the variable passing.

Comment: Thats correct. Alternatively, you could fetch the user from the auth facade/helper in your layout files , that way the variable will be available in all views that extend that layout

Answer (score 1):

Just use global `auth()` method in your blade to get authenticated user information.

```
@auth {{ auth()->user->id }} @endauth
```

or

```
@auth {{ auth()->user->name }} @endauth
```

or

```
@auth {{ auth()->user->email }} @endauth
```

If needed, you may specify which guard instance you would like to access:

```
$user = auth('web')->user();
```

**Updated**

Occasionally, you may need to share a piece of data with all views that are rendered by your application, check out the following link

[Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: @Luca Puddu something added,this might be helpful for you- checkout the updated edition.

Answer (score 0):

All of these are great answers. You could also use the Auth facade to accomplish this.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

$user = Auth::user()->name;
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/authentication